# Log4j2 using syslog appender and RFC5424

Tags: java, linux, log4j2, syslog

When I try to write some message to a remote Linux syslog, I use log4j2 with appender syslog and format=RFC5424, and BSD.My configuration file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
        <Appenders>
            <Syslog name="bsd" host="9.115.114.133" port="514" protocol="UDP" facility="local5"/>
            <Syslog name="RFC5424" format="RFC5424" host="9.115.114.133" 
                protocol="UDP" appName="MyApp" includeMDC="true"
                 facility="LOCAL5" enterpriseNumber="18060" newLine="true"
                  messageId="Audit" id="App"/>    
         </Appenders>
         <Loggers>
         <Logger name="test.main" level="warn">
         <AppenderRef ref="RFC5424"/>
         </Logger>
         <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="bsd"/>
        </Root>
        </Loggers>
```

When I running a testing program, I always got the error as follows:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No structured id name was supplied
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.StructuredDataId.(StructuredDataId.java:92)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.Rfc5424Layout.(Rfc5424Layout.java:139)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.Rfc5424Layout.createLayout(Rfc5424Layout.java:657)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SyslogAppender.createAppender(SyslogAppender.java:133)
    ... 20 more

2014-11-10 03:21:46,252 ERROR Null object returned for Syslog in Appenders.
2014-11-10 03:21:46,267 ERROR Unable to locate appender RFC5424 for logger test.main

How could I get rid of this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You need to include the `mdcId` attribute:

```xml
<Syslog name="RFC5424" format="RFC5424" host="9.115.114.133" 
        protocol="UDP" appName="MyApp" mdcId="mdc" includeMDC="true"
        facility="LOCAL5" enterpriseNumber="18060" newLine="true"
        messageId="Audit" id="App"/>
```