# Logger java with slf4j and send the logs to nginx local server

Tags: java, nginx, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have some obstacle related to Java logging. I wanna send my logs to the Nginx local server on my laptop. How can I implement this function using log4j or slf4j, could someone please help me with code implementation? Thanks

Comment: Hey @Maks, can you show us what you've tried so far? Including a short code snippet of your attempt would help.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to log to remote server is [RFC5424](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077657/13210997) or with [socket appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender) and maybe some of the other ones are going to fit your use case so check out the rest of the second site. Coding-wise you don't need to do anything if you already have `log4j` set up in your project, you just need to change the configuration file for `log4j`.

Or I completely misunderstood the question, let me know.

Comment: Oh thanks, no I don't have implementation of log4j. I need to start from scratch. I have some simple script and wanna send the logs from this script to nginx server on my laptop not remote). I just started the nginx service and nothing configured in it. So should i just send the logs from my app to nginx server or should i configure something on nginx server. Also question related with socket appender is it appropriate to use this appender in case I have server and actual program both on my laptop or should i use file appender? And which folder i should send my logs?

Comment: Why are you trying to send the logs to nginx server? What is the purpose of this server? I'm not sure what you're trying to get, but it doesn't matter where this server is, if it's serving some service on some port, you can just send your logs from application to that server with socket appender. I have plenty of production environments just sending data locally on localhost, that's perfectly fine. The rest is hard to answer because I don't know what is your use case.

Comment: Thanks i got it) Actually it is just testing task for understanding how to send logs to the server. Later I should rewrite it to send logs to Datadog for analyzing.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Consider upvoting and accepting answer if it helped it.